# Reverse lookup array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

how do you create a reverse lookup array in an efficient way?

e.g. `[5, 3, 1, 4, 2] => [3, 5, 2, 4, 1]`

Obviously a simple way is:

```
const input = [5, 3, 1, 4, 2];
const output = [];
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output[input[i] - 1] = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: btw, why not take the indices instead of one based value which requires always an offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your method is O(n): I don't think that can be beaten

You do have to go across every element in the input (to read it) and every element of the output (to write it): there is no getting out of that!

My only suggestion to slightly speed it up is to pre-size the output array.

```js
const input = [5, 3, 1, 4, 2];
const output = new Array(input.length);
input.forEach(
  (value, i) => output[value - 1] = i + 1
)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to just use the input and swap items within without creating another array?

Comment: For lurkers: While it's true that JavaScript arrays are sparse by nature and *in theory* (per spec), all "pre-sizing" the array does is set `length`, in fact modern JavaScript engines do take that length into account. V8, for instance, allocates memory for that many elements even though they start out empty.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do it without using at least some additional space. Even if you tried the principle of "this one needs to move to THAT position, so let's kick out the one at THAT position next...", you _might_ end up with cycles, without having covered them all. If you try to cover them all systematically, i.e. in order, you will run out of places to keep the ones that need to move.

Comment: @Eureka it is possible, by creating a reversed iterator instead.

Comment: Hi @vitaly - Can you add as a full answer? Myself, I can't see how a reversed iterator would help. I have no objection to my answer being de-accepted and a new one accepted, and am always keen to learn.

Comment: @Eureka Similar to [this](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops/blob/main/src/helpers.ts#L233) when you reverse the array logically, via a reverse iterable.

Comment: Ah, I don't think that would achieve what the original poster is requesting. They don't want to reverse the _order_. That would give [5, 3, 1, 4, 2] => [2, 4, 1, 3, 5].

They want to reverse the meaning of value and index, i.e. [5, 3, 1, 4, 2] => [3, 5, 2, 4, 1]. In the output, "3" means "The third element in the input, is the smallest". Then the "5" means, "the 5th element in the input is the second smallest", etc